# Insert whitespace between non-ascii characters in python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, whitespace

I am creating a dictionary that requires each letter of a string separated by whitespace. I am using join. The problem is when the string contains non-ascii characters. Join breaks them into two characters and the results is garbage.

Example:

```
>>> word = 'məsjø'
>>> ' '.join(word)
```

Gives me:

```
'm \xc9 \x99 s j \xc3 \xb8'
```

When what I want is:

```
'm ə s j ø'
```

Or even:

```
'm \xc9\x99 s j \xc3\xb8'
```

Comment: If this is Python 2.x, you need to define that as a Unicode string literal.

Comment: On my machine, the `' '.join()` works flawlessly with Python 3.x.  Can you specify which OS/version of Python you're using?

Comment: Was using 2.7. Just installed 3.2 and ' '.join() works with no problems! Thx.

Answer (score 3):

You should use unicode strings, i.e.

```
word = u'məsjø'
```

And don't forget to set the encoding of your Python source file at the beginning with

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

(Don't even think about using something other than UTF-8. ;))

**Update**: This only applies to Python < 3. If you're using Python >= 3, you would probably not have run into these problems in the first place. So if upgrading to 3.x is an option, it's the way to go -- it might not be in some cases because of library dependencies etc., unfortunately.

As mentioned in the comments, encoding issues might also result from a differently configured terminal, although that was not the problem here, apparently.

Comment: Or if the word is read from somewhere else, use `word.decode('utf-8')` to turn it into unicode.

Comment: In Python 3, this restriction is removed.  Also, it doesn't expressly answer the question.

Comment: I was assuming the OP does not use Python 3 because then this error would be unlikely... But you're right, would be nice to know for sure.

Comment: @Makoto: If the asker has run that code and got that result, he/she must be using Python 2. And in that situation, using a unicode literal is a perfectly good answer.

Comment: decode / encode worked for my 2.7 installation. Installed 3.2 and didn't need any decoding/encoding lines.Thx.

Comment: @ThomasK:  They *may* be using Python 2.x (in this case they were), but it could have also been that their terminal wasn't capable of printing UTF-8, and that's happened before.  Jan, if you want to edit a character or two, I'll upvote this answer.

Comment: @Makoto: No, if their terminal was in another encoding, they would either get an error, or see the escaped unicode characters (like `\u0259`). It wouldn't encode it to UTF-8 and then display the escaped bytes. And even if it did, it would put the spaces in first, so this question would never have been asked.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @Makoto and ThomasK. I updated my answer accordingly. Question to the taxonomists: Would it be appropriate to tag this question as python-2.x?